# How can i use script src?

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I am trying to use errLogin module in js code in html file.

THis is main.js file.

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"
const errLogin = false;
...

export default { errLogin }
```

THis is test.html file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>main</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Consolas, monospace;
        }
    </style>
     <script src="./account.js"></script>
     <script type="module">
        import { errLogin } from "./main.js"
        console.log(errLogin)
     </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p id="email"></p>
        <p id="password"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
            const CirculateData = () =>{
                for (let key in account)
                {
                    if (!errLogin) return account[key];
                    else return account[Number(key) + 1];
                }
            };
            
            document.querySelector("#email").innerHTML = CirculateData().email
            document.querySelector("#password").innerHTML = CirculateData().password
             
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

error message.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "puppeteer". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

this is folder structure.

[image]

How can I do it? How can I do it? How can I do it?How can I do it? How can I do it? How can I do it? How can I do it? How can I do it? How can I do it? How can I do it?

Comment: what is  folder structure? can u show me folder structure

Comment: added it! Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Type module work with src argument, then browsers don't know about import|export, you need Webpack or another bundler

Comment: How should I search?